# C - Memcpy two int's to a single Void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void

I am trying to copy two ints into a void pointer, and be able to access them, so far no luck.

```
void *buffer;
buffer = malloc (sizeof(int) + sizeof(int))
memcpy (&buffer, &int1, sizeof(int));
memcpy (&buffer + sizeof(int), &int2, sizeof(int));
printf ("%d", *(int*)buffer);
```

When printing, all I get is the value in the first 4 bytes. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `pNewBuffer` is what?

Comment: what is `pNewBuffer`?

Comment: What's `sizeof(int)` on your machine? If it's 4 bytes, `printf` will print 4 bytes (even though you `malloc` 8)

Comment: You're printing with `%d` and casting the pointer to an `int*` type. It will print an `int` for how ever long that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are copying to pointer of the pointer.

Change these two lines:

```
memcpy (&buffer, &int1, sizeof(int));
memcpy (&buffer + sizeof(int), &int2, sizeof(int));
```

To be this:

```
memcpy (buffer, &int1, sizeof(int));
memcpy (buffer + sizeof(int), &int2, sizeof(int));
```

Better form:

```
void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
int* intbuffer = (int*)buffer;

memcpy(intbuffer, &int1, sizeof(int));
memcpy(intbuffer+1, &int2, sizeof(int));
```

You can even avoid the memcpy altogether:

```
void* buffer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
int* intbuffer = (int*)buffer;

intbuffer[0] = int1;
intbuffer[1] = int2;
```

The corresponding `printf("%d", *(int*)buffer);` works for all three examples above.

Comment: The post is marked C, so no type cast from `void *` to `int *` is necessary. You can also avoid the use of the `buffer` alltogether. `int *intbuffer = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem here is this part

```
memcpy (&buffer, ...);
//      ^
```

First of all, if you want an "array" or `int` then why don't you use a pointer to `int`? You can always cast it to a generic `void *` later. This will solve *one* problem, which is the pointer arithmetic you attempt to do in the second `memcpy` call.

Going back to my highlighted part, using the address-of operator for `buffer` is *wrong* and will pass a pointer to where the *variable* `buffer` is stored, not the address where `buffer` is pointing. Drop the address-of operator there.

To sum it up:

```
int *int_buffer = malloc(sizeof *int_buffer * 2);
memcpy(int_buffer, &int1, sizeof int1);     // or &int_buffer[0]
memcpy(int_buffer + 1, &int2, sizeof int2); // or &int_buffer[1]

void *buffer = int_buffer;
```

---

For your printing, you only tell `printf` to print the very first `int` element. If you want to print both `int` elements you need to tell `printf` to do that.